# How do I convert a propertyChangeListener into a Lookup?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-platform

I have an OutlineView displaying a list of available data from a database.  What I would like to do is when the user uses the QuickFilter have the number of filtered results be displayed nearby. I think I'm getting the propertyChangeListener with:
`outlineView.getOutline().getPropertyChangeListener(ETable.PROP_QUICK_FILTER);`
I'm confused how to move forward from here with adding the `pcl` to my ProxyLookup in my TopComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what I was needing to do this was:

```
outlineView.getOutline().addPropertyChangeListener(ETable.PROP_QUICK_FILTER, new PropertyChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt){
        //Able to get the current number of displayed rows here
    }
}
```

I know it seems simple but this had taking hours of my time just to get this.  Doing this to help any future needs of people.